# why is the 'space after' different between two sIFR headlines?

Tags: sifr

At clientarea.hexatrope.com/nathanael/ I am using sIFR to create two headlines in the main content column. For some reason, when the headline is two lines long, there is less space between the bottom of it and the following paragraph than when the headline is one line long. Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Flash issue, given that the inconsistency occurs when the number of lines is different, there's nothing to be done about this at this point.

Comment: Is this a known bug that's in the list for the next release? It seems a correction could possibly be made with textfield.numLines.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#numLines

Comment: I don't think its a known bug. Indeed the one possible solution is extra tuning depending on the number of lines, but that's just ugly.

Comment: It would be a bit hacky, but I'm thinking that for a project whose goal is good type on the web, the typographical improvement would warrant it in this case. Is that a reasonable thought?

Comment: It is, but as you'll probably have noticed, I haven't spend much time on sIFR 'lately'. Come to think of it, I believe this is already in the to-do list somewhere.